# Database Architecture Many-to-Many-to-Many

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, architecture, data-modeling

I have got an issue how to change a model of database:

For now we have predefined table `Categories`
and let's say tables `Places` and `People` which can be assigned to categories so it looks like this:

```
People <=> PeopleCategories <=> Categories <=> PlaceCategories <=> Places
```

(People can have many categories, categories can have many people, places can have many categories, categories can have many places)

But now there is a new requirement:

On person profile show all corresponding places based on categories (so far no problem) and add a tick box modeling some attribute (for example show on front-end as favorite place). The same from the other side on Place profile mark people assigned to at least one same category with a tick box.

I wonder whether there is some nice way to model this - the only thing which came to my mind is to add a new `PeoplePlaces` table but then I have to manually control whether people or places did not change their categories and they are still assigned and so on - There will be quite a problem with consistency of data which I will have to manage on application layer.

The second thing I could probably do is to delete categories totally and make it only on `PeoplePlaces` level but I will lose some simplicity for user: there are like 10 predefined categories which user can select so the linking between People and Places is quite automatic on front-end and only admin should see which places are assigned to which people and manage that tick box I was talking about

What would you suggest for this architecture? Thanks in advance! (It is a MySQL db if it is important for some kind of solution but this is more a general architecture thing)

Comment: This is similar to this question at DBA.SE: [Are there DBMS that allow a Foreign Key that References a View (and not only base tables)?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/are-there-dbms-that-allow-a-foreign-key-that-references-a-view-and-not-only-bas) Please read all the answers and the discussions in the comments, it's not trivial to be implemented.

Comment: @ypercube: yes that is exactly what I am facing, I see you placed that  question. What did you use in the end? I will probably try the constraint solution as my tables will probably not change very often. Thank you for that link!

Comment: It was more a theoretical problem for me, rather a practical one. For MySQL, I think I'd use the constraint solution (which will also need either DELETE triggers for the `PeopleCategories` and `PlaceCategories` tables or some other way to customize the DELETE operations on those 2 tables.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you need to ensure that a person can *only* favor a place that is connected to the same category as the person herself?

If so, take a look at the following model:

[image]

We don't link the "endpoints" directly, and instead "link the links". This allows us to migrate PERSON_CATEGORY.CATEGORY_ID and PLACE_CATEGORY.CATEGORY_ID  into the FAVORED_PLACE table, and "merge" them there, producing a single FAVORED_PLACE.CATEGORY_ID field (note `FK1,FK2`in the diagram above).

As a consequence, if a person is connected to a place, that must be done through a common category.

Furthermore, since CATEGORY_ID is outside PERSON_CATEGORY's PK, a particular combination of person and place can be used only once, even if they match through multiple categories. Effectively, you pick one common category as "special". If a place (or person) is removed from the special category, you'll need to pick another common category to serve as special. If there are no common categories left, the corresponding row in FAVORED_PLACE will not be allowed to exist anymore.

Comment: I really like this model but as far as I understand there is still some logic left for the application layer - if a person unsets a certain category i can populate cascade delete BUT not always as they can be linked by some other category - and this is what app has to check (or maybe trigger could solve this but I am not allowed to use them right now). Am I right? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: It doesn't have to be in the application layer. You can write a DELETE procedure (for the `Person_Category` table and another for the other table) that takes care of that. And then allow your application to only do deletes calling these procedures.

Comment: @kuncajs If you want to move to a different "special" category, then yes, there is some special logic involved (otherwise you can just ON DELETE CASCADE). If for some reason you can't package that logic in a trigger, you can still encapsulate it in a way that makes reuse easy (as ypercube suggested).

Comment: @kuncajs However a **pure** trigger solution (without FKs on CATEGORY_ID) could very easily lead to a race condition: transaction T1 removes person from category, but T2 connects that person and place (since it thinks they still have common category, since T1 hasn't committed yet). You'd have to use locking to avoid that, which is easy to get wrong. If you have FKs, the DBMS itself ensures the referential integrity cannot be broken.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think deleting Categories is a good idea.

What you are doing is introducing a new entity - PersonsFavouritePlaces - which relates People and Place directly rather than via a Category. It is sensible that a PersonsFavouritePlace be limited to a Person and a Place linked by Category, so it should probably reference PeopleCategories and PlaceCategories rather than the People and Category tables.

The table would look like:

```
create table PeopleFavourtiePlace
(
  ID int not null, -- Primary key
  PeopleCategoriesId int not null, -- FK to PK of PerpleCategories
  PlaceCategoriesId int not null -- FK to PK of PlaceCategories
)
```

I don't know whether MySql supports cascading deletes, but if so the two FK's should have that turned on so when someone deselects a category (deleting the PeopleCategories row) if it linked to a favourite place in that category it too gets deleted.

However, if a person links to a place via multiple categories then it gets complicated....

Comment: This is too simplistic. It allows rows to be added in this table that relates a Person with a Place where there is no Category that joins them.